# Can IO utilities writel and readl be used on physical addresses

Tags: c, linux

Can IO utils such as writel and readl be used on physical addresses, or do I always need to first map the physical memory into my virtual space, and then use the pointer as the argument to writel/readl?

Comment: What exactly are you referring to by in32 and out32? As near I can tell Linux doesn't have anything by those names.

Comment: @RossRidge: My bad - they are writel and readl.

Comment: You should give more context about what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is going to be platform dependent. If you search through the code you will see writel and readl typically are implemented in the architecture specific files (in arch/ in the kernel tree), as assembly language calls. On some platforms it is possible it might work. However, it makes more sense to always call ioremap to get a pointer. This will help with portability and if not needed on a particular platform it would be optimized out anyhow.

See:

[Free-Electrons writel](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=writel)

[Free-Electrons writel](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=readl)